# Issue with connecting/excuting PHP through gulp-connect

Tags: php, gulp

I am trying to use/run Google Web-Starter-Kit with PHP code and surfing through internet I found [gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php#hostname) which helps to run PHP files inside gulp server(we can connect gulp with our local php service). So that i installed **gulp-connect-php** and added the following code to `gulpfile.js`
code:

```
var  connect = require('gulp-connect-php');
gulp.task('connect', function() {
connect.server({
hostname: '0.0.0.0',
bin: 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php.exe',
ini: 'C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php.ini',
port: 8000,
base: 'dev'
});
});
gulp.task('default', ['connect']);
```

and entered the below command to execute gulp server with gulp-conntect

```
>gulp connect
```

but it throwing some ERROR with path i specified for PHP applicatoin.

ERROR:

```
E:\my-project>gulp connect
[10:51:57] Using gulpfile E:\my-project\gulpfile.js
[10:51:57] Starting 'connect'...
[10:51:57] Finished 'connect' after 12 ms
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/php.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I don't know where the issue lies on. please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

An ENOENT error usually indicates that a file or directory is missing. Seeing that you are on windows, this would most likely be due to a wrong direction of slashes.

Try

```
 bin: 'C:\\wamp\\bin\\php\\php5.5.12\\php.exe'
```

(same for ini) and make sure this file really exists! Other than that, if you can call `php` directly from your command line, you shouldn't need to point to the EXE file at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still not working..and file is really exist.